# Cant find private key file after using openSSL

Tags: macos, openssl

Im trying to use openssl on my mac to generate a csr. the problem is that I cant find the private key after it is generated. I think its being created in some other directory. but I cant find it. These are the commands that I use and the error message that I get:

```
user$ openssl genrsa 2048  -out myKey.pem

Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
........................+++
...................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
--------
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

user$ openssl req -sha256 -new -key myKey.pem -out csr.pem

Error opening Private Key myKey.pem
921:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or     directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-    47.1/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fopen('myKey.pem','r')
921:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:
unable to load Private Key
```

How do I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genrsa.html):

> numbits
>
> - the size of the private key to generate in bits. *This must be the last option specified.*

Your `-out` argument is ignored. This works:

```
openssl genrsa -out myKey.pem 2048
```

or

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > myKey.pem
```